# Смена картинки перетаскиванием вертикальной линии

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток, подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать смену фоновой картинки на сайте движением вертикальной линии
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень даже просто, например вот так: 
https://jsfiddle.net/daniel217/5b88wn2h/7/

```js
$(function() {
  $('.photoToggle').mousemove(function(e) {
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    var elem_left = pos.left;
    var elem_top = pos.top;
    // положение курсора внутри элемента
    var Xinner = e.pageX - elem_left;
    var Yinner = e.pageY - elem_top;
    $('.photoToggle-top').css('width', Xinner)
    $('.photoToggle-toggle').css({
      'left': Xinner - 20,
      'top': Yinner - 20
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.photoToggle {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.photoToggle-top {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background-image: url(http://www.conceptcarz.com/images/Alfa%20Romeo/Alfa-Romeo-MiTo-Image-007-800.jpg);
}

.photoToggle-toggle {
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 380px;
  z-index: 3;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(66, 134, 244);
}

.photoToggle-btn {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url(http://premieropt.ru/site/themes/default/img/custom-img/4.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="photoToggle">
  <div class="photoToggle-top"></div>
  <div class="photoToggle-toggle"></div>
  <div class="photoToggle-btn"></div>
</div>
```

P.S. Стилизовать по вкусу.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: @WhiteFox Если подошел мой ответ, отметьте его галочкой